missing ARNs for public AWS Lambda layers for aws-sdk
ChatGPT tells me this:

AWS provides a public layer containing the AWS SDK for JavaScript. You can use this layer in your Lambda function.

And that the public layer for AWS SDK for node.js 14.x in the us-east-1 region is:
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:668099181075:layer:AWSLambdaPowertoolsNodeJS:10

I would love to avoid having to build or maintain my own custom layer for aws-sdk in node 18 or 20.  Can anyone confirm that public aws-sdk layers exist, and if so, where can i find a list of them?

Note that each AWS Lambda Node.js runtime includes an appropriate AWS SDK for JavaScript.

Weird.  so why can't I use a statement like
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
in the node 18 or 20 runtimes?

From the Node18 runtime on, the AWS SDK v3 is included in the runtime; up to that, is was v2. v3 clients have different namespace and you'll have to e.g. import  {LambdaClient} from '@aws-sdk/client-lambda'.
